Git merge disrupts `git svn info` metadata
I've successfully used git svn to fetch a project from a very old svn server.
The output of git svn info shows:

master points to https://svn-server/repos/myProject.
feature-new points to https://svn-server/repos/branches/myProject.

However, merging feature-new into master changes the mapping, causing master to point to https://svn-server/repos/myProject/myProject/myBranch.
How can I fix this?
SVN repository:

trunk: https://svn-server/repos/myProject
branch: https://svn-server/repos/branches/myProject

Procedures for fetching:
1. Clone from svn
git svn init https://svn-server/repos --trunk=myProject --branches=branches/{myProject} myProject

2. Setting the authorsfile
git config svn.authorsfile ~/authors.txt


Edit content of .git/config:

[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false  
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://svn-server/repos/myProject
        fetch = myProject:refs/remotes/git-svn/trunk
        branches = branches/{myProject}/*:refs/remotes/feature-new/*
[svn]
        authorsfile = ~/authors.txt


fetch

git svn fetch


confirm the remote branches:

git branch -r

results:
feature-new/myProject
git-svn/trunk


checkout feature-new/myProject and rename:

git checkout feature-new/myProject
git switch -c feature-new


Do you have any git-svn-id in your Git repository? Those do not play well with merges. That is why rebase is preferred over merge when it comes to git-svn

git rebase feature-new on master still causes git svn info on master show https://svn-server/repos/branches/myProject.

After a lot of trial and error, git merge --no-commit --no-ff feature-new seems to be the most suitable solution. However, all commits between master and feature-new do not get pushed to the SVN server when I run git svn dcommit.

I can't really recommend this, but then I can't really recommend using an ancient SVN repository either!
Make the entire branch diff a patch and apply it
git svn fetch
git checkout feature
git diff master > ../feature.patch
git checkout -  # back to master
git apply ../feature.patch

I don't have a test instance, but you can make what happened a little more obvious by embedding the git log into the commit message, which has a fairly high limit Maximum length for SVN comment

Finally, though it may not be feasible for your case, converting the project to git or mercurial may be the best move for sustainability
